# Using jqGrid's emptyrecords option

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

So I have this grid. It's a very nice grid. Lovely, really. Except when I have nothing to populate it with. In that case, I'd really like to display a message indicating that, "No URLs have been loaded for evaluation.", but either I'm missing something critical or the `emptyrecords` option isn't behaving the way I'd expect. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
var pages = <?php echo $json_encoded_array ?>;

$('#oversight-sample').jqGrid({
  altRows:   true,
  autowidth: true,
  caption:   'Evaluated URLs',
  colNames:  ['Actions', 'URL', 'Fetch Date'],
  colModel:  [
    { align: 'center', name: 'actions', index: 'actions', title: false, width: 60, resizable: false, sortable: false },
    { name: 'url', index: 'url', width: 400 },
    { align: 'center', name: 'created', index: 'created', width: 125, sorttype: 'date' }
  ],
  data:         pages,
  datatype:     'local',
  emptyrecords: 'No URLs have been loaded for evaluation.',
  forceFit:     true,
  height:       'auto',
  hoverrows:    true,
  sortname:     'created',
  pager:        '#url-pager',
  viewrecords:  true
});
```

If records *do* exist, then everything looks about like I'd expect it to look. Is there something else I need to do to get the `emptyrecords` message to display when there are none?

I'm using jqGrid 3.8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should verify how are the value of `data` parameter (the value of `pages` in your case). I suppose the value is `null` or `{}` instead of `[]`.

**UPDATED**: You can also consider to set current page from 1 to 0 how it shows [the small demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EmptyMsg.htm).

**UPDATED 2**: Of cause you can place the text about empty rows on the place of the table. In the case you have to remove `height: 'auto'` to be able to see the text. Look at [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EmptyMsgInBody.htm) which show this.

Comment: Hmmm. Good point. I'll ensure that I'm capturing an empty array. I imagine that you're right and the value is an empty string or null.

Comment: Neither of those seem to work the way they do in your example. Does the `emptyrecords` message always appear in the lower right of the pager panel? If so, that's not what I'm after so the question may be moot. I'd really like the message to display between the header and the footer of the table.

Comment: @Rob Wilkerson: What do you mean under "Neither of those seem to work the way they do in your example"? Do you can't reproduce my example in your environment? I created for you a simple demo which show how to display the message between the header and the footer of the table (see **UPDATED 2** part of my answer).

Comment: @Oleg: `grid.hide()` used in this demos breaks inline add. Inline add adds new row but since grid is hidden, added row is not displayed. How to fix this so that inline added row is visible ? I fixed this by adding `$(t).show()` to jqGrid addRowData method. Is this best fix?

Comment: @Andrus: It seems you can create div `emptyMsgDiv` as div with relative or absolute position and place it *over* the grid body with large enough "z-Index". In the case you will don't need to use any `.hide()` or `.show()` methods on the grid. In any way if you show the div explicitly you have to hide it also explicitly. You can do this before call of `addRowData` or inside of some callback. You can use now new events. For example in `jqGridAfterInsertRow` event you can test p.reccount === 0 and show or hide the `emptyMsgDiv`.

Comment: @Oleg: I used `$grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#grid_toppager', { addParams: { addRowParams: { oneditfunc  : function () { $grid.show();}}}});` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone here has an issue with the JQGrid not showing the message "No Records To View", ensure that you have set the `viewrecords: true` option.

> **emptyrecords** - Display the information when the returned (or the current) number of records is zero. This option is valid only if viewrecords option is set to true.